# Unable to create a Flutter project Ubuntu

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

Running `flutter doctor -v` on Ubuntu, outputs the below:

```
#0 throwToolExit (package: flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)  
#1 DefaultPub._runWithStdioInherited package: flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:447:7)  asynchronous suspension>  
#2 _DefaultPub.get (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:32315)  asynchronous suspenston>  
#3 PubDependencies.update  package:flutter_tools/src/flutter_cache.dart:126:5)  asynchronous suspenston>  
#4 Cache.updateAll (package: flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:715:9)  <asynchronous suspenston>  
#5 FlutterCommand.vertfyThenRunCommand  (package: flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1612:7)  <asynchronous suspension>  
#6 FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>  (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1350:27)  <asynchronous suspenston>  
#7 AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>  package: flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)  ( <asynchronous suspenston>  
#8 CommandRunner.runCommand (packagezargs/command_runner.dart:212:13)  <asynchronous suspenston>  
#9 FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand,<anonymous closures (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:34819)  <asynchronous suspenston>  
#10 AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>  (package: flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)  <asynchronous suspenston>  
#11 FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand  (package: flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:29415) <asynchronous suspenston>  
#12 run.<anonymous closure> <anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:112:9)  <asynchronous suspension>  
#13 AppContext.run.anonymous closure>  (package: flutter tools/src/base/context.dart/150:19)  <asynchronous suspenston> 
#14 main (package: flutter_tools/executable.dart190:3)  <asynchronous suspension>
```

It is not giving me the proper analysis of the flutter project.

Comment: have you run flutter doctor ? is everything fine on your flutter installation ?